# How to specify generic file name in SO questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions

> Example:
>
> Say an OP posts on StackOverflow a question titled "Why am I getting
> MyFile.h: No such file or directory error?".

What the OP cares about in the example above is not specifically about "MyFile.h" but why he/she is getting the error. But since the OP has mentioned a specific file name, it clouds the ability to search efficiently on SO for users who have the same error in the future. And this makes duplicate questions much more likely.

> How can we post the above post with a generic file name?

So instead of saying "Myfile.h",
we might say "*.h" or "FILE.h"(maybe a pre-defined name to designate that it represents any filename). I've wondered this for a long time, as it would help the search-ability of SO.

Comment: In that example, the error *message* ("No such file or directory") is more relevant, and I'd hope that a basic search would find it. I'm not sure the file name being present matters, *as long as the error message is also*.

Comment: It would still be nice for SO to have some system of regex, just like any decent shell. Even if said regex functionality were not incorporated in the SO search functionality, it would greatly improve searching, readability, and duplication-reduction to have some sort of agreed-upon standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this type of stuff a lot when googling with error text. Except my version would be SomeOtherFile.h. Usually I just omit the filename to search, and get a lot of results. A common replacement for something like that is 4 x's (not sure why).

```
Why am I getting xxxx.h: No such file or directory error?
```